# Does the order of connecting the low pass and high pass filter make any difference?

Tags: prototyping, active-filter

Is there any advantage in connecting up high pass filter first and then low pass filter to achieve a simple band pass filter. Or the other way around is better? Will there be any change based on the order of connection of filters?

Comment: "connecting up high pass filter first and then low pass filter" You high-pass filter **high frequency component** and then low-pass filter it away ?! Try to rethink about the order.

Comment: @LongPham if you're building a band pass, then you have to remove both low and high frequencies. So the low pass would have a higher cutoff than the high pass.

Comment: Yes, but his circuit order will result in an all stop filter.

Comment: @LongPham, you're rather oddly taking the low-pass filter's fc to be a lower frequency than the high-pass filter's fc. I think you're confusing what 'high' and 'low' frequencies mean here in these filters. Putting it through high-pass with fc of 1 kHz then low-pass with fc of 1 MHz will be a band-pass filter, won't it.

Comment: @LongPham: It will be an all stop only if the LP cut-off is above the HP cut-off. An audio system, for example, might have a high-pass filter with -3 dB at 20 Hz and a low-pass with -3 dB at 20 kHz. That wouldn't be an all-stop.

Comment: Besides what alex.forencich said, using the lowpass first might cut the high frequency noise earlier, might not, but it's good to remember that one path the noise does propagate through is the supply.

Comment: Oh, sorry guys. My mistake.

Comment: when I take the frequency response by connecting low pass first and high pass after that or the other way around, the response remains the same. Is there any other advantage in deciding the order of connection

Answer (score 1):

One thing to worry about when cascading filters is loading. It's possible that when this is taken in to consideration, the component values will be nicer for one configuration.

Comment: Unless you buffer it :)

Comment: True, but that requires an extra amplifier, and if you can design the circuit to work without that, then you can save on cost, complexity, and power consumption.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the cascading of filters does not load down the first one, I would put the low-pass filter last to block any and all background noise, including any created by the high-pass filter.

I am also assuming you are using quality low-noise op-amps, like the LM1028/TL072/TL074 or OPA or SSM series.